# How can I fill 2 vectors

Tags: c++, vector

For some reason program ends after prompting for second `std::vector`. I'm guessing that `std::cin` function has some problems when its called for second time

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    vector<int> v1, v2, v3;
    cout << "First vector:" << endl;
    while (cin >> n) v1.push_back(n);
    for (auto m : v1)
        cout << m << '\t';
    cout << " " << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cout << "Seccond vector:" << endl;
    while (cin >> n) v2.push_back(n);
    for (auto m : v2)
        cout << m << '\t';
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you sending EOF in the input to stop the first loop?

Comment: You probably need `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` after the `cin,clear()`, depending on the actual input you give to the program. Could you please show that?

Comment: I'm sending in char to stop the first loop

Comment: @baum-mit-augen thank you! Using cin.ignore instead of cin.sync solved the problem

Comment: If you [edit] some sample input into your question, it would actually be sort of useful. I did not find an exact duplicate after a short search.